# MongoDB: Transform array of objects to array of arrays

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a collection named "records" that contains documents in the following form:

```
{
  "name": "a"
  "items": [
    {
      "a": "5", 
      "b": "1", 
      "c": "2"
    }, 
    {
      "a": "6", 
      "b": "3", 
      "c": "7"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to keep the data just as it is in the database (to make the data easy to read and interpret). But I'd like to run a query that returns the data in the following form:

```
{
  "name": "a"
  "items": [
    ["5", "1", "2"],
    ["6", "3", "7"],
  ]
}
```

Is this possible with pymongo? I know I can run a query and translate the documents using Python, but I'd like to avoid iterating over the query result if possible.

Comment: Would this [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wjDxgPrC0Nd) work for you?

Comment: Also, if it suits your need, please disconsider the `in: { $toString: "$$item.v" }` expression; just found out you could use `in: "$$item.v"` instead.

Comment: @Rfroes87 you nailed it! Could you please add an answer with your code and some description of what's happening in there? If you could add some comments on the performance considerations of this approach vs simply looping over the documents and modifying them e.g. with Python, I'd be super grateful!

Answer (score 0):

> I have a table named "records"

Collection

> Is this possible with pymongo?

Yes

> Any pointers on how to approach this would be super helpful!

I'd suggest you to use a [view](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/views/#views) to transform your data during a query in MongoDB.
In this way, you can get transformed data and apply `find` to already transformed data if you need.

```
db.createCollection(
    "view_name",
    {"viewOn": "original_collection_name",
     "pipeline": [{$unwind: "$items"},
                  {$project: {name: 1, items: {$objectToArray: "$items"}}},
                  {$project: {name: 1, items: {$concatArrays: ["$items.v"]}}}, 
                  {$group: {_id: "$_id", name: {$first: "$name"},
                            items: {$push: "$items"}}}]
    }
)

> db.view_name.find({name: "a"})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5fc3dbb69cb76f866582620f"), "name" : "a", "items" : [ [ "5", "1", "2" ], [ "6", "3", "7" ] ] }

> db.view_name.find({"items": {$in: [["5", "1", "2"]]}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5fc3dbb69cb76f866582620f"), "name" : "a", "items" : [ [ "5", "1", "2" ], [ "6", "3", "7" ] ] }

> db.view_name.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5fc3dbb69cb76f866582620f"), "name" : "a", "items" : [ [ "5", "1", "2" ], [ "6", "3", "7" ] ] }
```

Query:

```
db.original_collection_name.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$items"},
    {$project: {name: 1, items: {$objectToArray: "$items"}}}, 
    {$project: {name: 1, items: {$concatArrays: ["$items.v"]}}}, 
    {$group: {_id: "$_id", name: {$first: "$name"}, items: {$push: "$items"}}}])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/#mongodb-expression-exp.-objectToArray) and [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) transformations:

```
// { name: "a", items: [ { a: "5", b: "1", c: "2" }, { a: "6", b: "3", c: "7" } ] }
db.collection.aggregate([

  { $set: { items: { $map: { input: "$items", as: "x", in: { $objectToArray: "$$x" } } } } },
  // {
  //   name: "a",
  //   items: [
  //     [ { k: "a", v: "5" }, { k: "b", v: "1" }, { k: "c", v: "2" } ],
  //     [ { k: "a", v: "6" }, { k: "b", v: "3" }, { k: "c", v: "7" } ]
  //   ]
  // }

  { $set: { items: { $map: { input: "$items", as: "x", in: "$$x.v" } } } }
])
// { name: "a", items: [["5", "1", "2"], ["6", "3", "7"]] }
```

This maps `items`' elements as key/value arrays such that `{ field: "value" }` becomes `[ { k: "field", v: "value" } ]`. This way whatever the field name, we can easily access the value using `v`, which is the role of the second `$set` stage: `"$$x.v"`.

This has the benefit of avoiding heavy stages such as unwind/group.

Note that you can also imbricate the second `$map` within the first; but that's probably less readable.